# inputMismatchException Runtime Error

Tags: java

Getting inputMismatchException error when try to run the following code.
The input file to the scanner is of the format:

" Afghanistan 30419928
   Akrotiri 15700 " and so on.
The Error is at `double value= in.nextDouble();` . Thank youu.

```
String filename = "population.txt";
        File inputFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

        String country = in.next();
        double largest = in.nextDouble();



        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            double value = in.nextDouble();


            if(value>largest)
            {
                largest=value;
                country=in.next();
            }
            else
            in.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

`double value = in.nextDouble();` is readding `Akrotiri`, it's a **string**

Answer (score 1):

You're using `nextDouble()` when your input is an unconvertible `String` (Akrotiri)

```
String country = in.next();           <-- Afghanistan 
double largest = in.nextDouble();     <-- 30419928 

while(in.hasNext())
{
    double value = in.nextDouble();  <-- Akrotiri
```

---

### 2 Solutions

```
while(in.hasNextDouble) {
    double value = in.nextDouble();    <-- 15700
```

OR

```
while(in.hasNext()) {
    String value = in.next();         <-- Akrotiri
```